# NFS Vagrant on Fedora 22

Tags: vagrant, rpc, fedora, nfs, libvirt

I'm trying to run Vagrant using libvirt as my provider. Using rsync is unbearable since I'm working with a huge shared directory, but vagrant does succeed when the nfs setting is commented out and the standard rsync config is set.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", mount_options: ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
```

Vagrant hangs forever on this step here after running vagrant up

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
```

In my Vagrantfile I have this uncommented and the rsync config commented out, which turns NFS on.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

When Vagrant is running it echos this out to the terminal.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  nfs-server.service
Job for nfs-server.service failed. See "systemctl status nfs-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Results of systemctl status nfs-server.service

```
dillon@localhost ~ $ systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-05-29 22:24:47 PDT; 22s ago
  Process: 3044 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3040 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3044 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur rpc.nfsd[3044]: rpc.nfsd: writing fd to kernel failed: errno 111 (Connection refused)
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur rpc.nfsd[3044]: rpc.nfsd: unable to set any sockets for nfsd
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: Failed to start NFS server and services.
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: Unit nfs-server.service entered failed state.
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: nfs-server.service failed.
```

The journelctl -xe log has a ton of stuff in it so I won't post all of it here, but there are some things in the bold red.

```
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur rpc.mountd[3024]: Could not bind socket: (98) Address already in use
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur rpc.mountd[3024]: Could not bind socket: (98) Address already in use
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur rpc.statd[3028]: failed to create RPC listeners, exiting
May 29 22:24:47 localhost.sulfur systemd[1]: Failed to start NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
```

Before I ran vagrant up I looked to see if there were any process binding to port 98 with netstat -tulpn and did not see anything and in fact while vagrant is hanging I ran netstat -tulpn again to see what was binding to port 98 and didn't see anything. (checked for both current user and root)

**UPDATE**: Haven't gotten any responses.

I wasn't able to figure out the current issue I'm having. I tried using lxc instead, but gets stuck on booting. I'd also prefer not to use VirtualBox, but the issue seems to lie within nfs not the hypervisor. Going to try using the rsync-auto feature Vagrant provides, but I'd prefer to get nfs working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when using libvirt the user is given control over nfs and rpcbind, and Vagrant doesn't even try to touch those things like I had assumed it did. Running these solved my issue:

```
service rpcbind start
service nfs stop
service nfs start
```

Answer (score 1):

The systemd unit dependencies of `nfs-server.service` contain `rpcbind.target` but not `rpcbind.service`.

One simple solution is to create a file `/etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service` containing:

```
.include /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service

[Unit]
Requires=rpcbind.service
After=rpcbind.service
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7, all I needed to do
was install the missing rpcbind, like this:

yum -y install rpcbind

systemctl enable rpcbind

systemctl start rpcbind

systemctl restart nfs-server

Took me over an hour to find out and try this though :)

Michel

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with NFS mounts using both the libvirt and the VirtualBox provider on Fedora 22. After a lot of gnashing of teeth, I managed to figure out that it was a firewall issue. Fedora seems to ship with a `firewalld` service by default. Stopping that service - `sudo systemctl stop firewalld` - did the trick for me.

Of course, ideally you would configure this firewall rather than disable it entirely, but I don't know how to do that.